# AsynchronousSocketChannel. Условие срабатывания Callback

Tags: java, nio2

Есть такой код

```
AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
.......
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
channel.read(buf, buf, CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    if (result != -1)
      System.out.println(attacment.hasRemaining());
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
     // process error
  }
});
```

и аналогичный для записи

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
..........
buf.rewind();
channel.write(buf, buf, CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer attachment) {
    if (result != -1)
      System.out.println(attacment.hasRemaining());
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
     // process error
  }
});
```

Вопрос - всегда ли эти методы будут выводить `false` или возможна ситуация когда прочитано/записано байт меньше, чем в буфере и операцию нужно будет повторить?

Comment: Что должно вызываться с помощью callback?

Comment: @RomanC А от этого зависит алгоритм работы метода `read`? Ну пусть в калбаке находится парсер пакета. Размер пакета 1000 байт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback срабатывает при приеме одного TCP пакета. Какая длина этого пакета - заранее неизвестно, поэтому callback может сработать при приеме даже одного байта (например `telnet` посылает пакеты размером один байт и на каждый пакет срабатывает callback)

Чтобы дождаться строго определенного числа байт я использовал такой код

```
class Attacment {
  AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
  ByteBuffer buf;
}

Attacment att = new Attacment();
att.channel = ....
.......
att.buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
channel.read(buf, att, CompletionHandler<Integer, Attacment>() {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, Attacment att) {
    if (result == -1) {
      att.channel.close();
      // Process error
    } else if (att.buf.hasRemaining()) {
      attacment.channel.read(att.buf, att, this);
    } else {
      // process packet
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
     // process error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае метода `read` вам может прийти данных больше, чем есть места в буфере `buf`. В этом случае будет выведено `true` и понадобится повторное чтение.

В случае метода `write`, если ваш сервер генерирует поток данных достаточный, чтобы забить буферы отправки, может возникнуть ситуация, когда вы не сможете записать в канал содержимое `buf` полностью. Тогда будет будет выведено `true` и понадобится повторная запись.

Лучше всего писать код с учётом возможности неполной отправки и приёма данных.

Comment: Я ожидаю именно 1000 байт и хочу записать именно 1000 байт (такая длина пакета в системе). У меня может вызваться callback **ДО** того как будет прочитан/записан весь пакет? Или система гарантирует, что в момент вызова callback **все** 1000 байт прочитаны/записаны или мне пришло `-1` при ошибке?

Comment: Колбэк будет вызван как только придёт хоть что-нибудь. Пришёл один байт - вызов, пришло ещё 999 - вызов.

Comment: На запись аналогично?

Comment: В теории да, но на практике весь буфер обычно уходит сразу одним куском.